# What does '$N × Q$' represent in this relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In relation $\{(x, y) ∈ N × Q | y = \sqrt x\}$
what does '$N × Q$' represent?

Comment: Knight takes Queen.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb N$ is the set of [*natural* numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Notation) and $\mathbb Q$ is the set of [*rationals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number).

$\mathbb N \times \mathbb Q$ is the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two sets : $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$.

Thus, $(x, y) \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb Q$ means that $(x, y)$ is an [ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair) where $x$ is a *natural* and $y$ is a *rational*.

Comment: ok thanks, why does ℕ represent x and ℚ represent y but not the other way around?

Comment: @user604574: $x$ is the left element of the pair, and $\mathbb N$ is the left operand to the $\times$. Similarly $y$ and $\mathbb Q$ are on the right.

Comment: @user604574 - because in an *ordered pair* the "order" matters.